# Java lombok unit tests for getters setters

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-coverage, lombok

I am using `lombok` in my Java project annotating my object's private member variables with `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations. We know that those getters and setters would work as expected. So we don't really need those to be unit tested. However, that brings down the `code coverage` of the code in unit testing.

Is there a way to tell the unit testing engine that the getters and setters generated by lombok need not be tested?

Comment: 1. You should not write unittest only to raise the coverage. Unittest shall provide safety for refactorings and assist bug hunting. Unittest on getters/setters do not support either one.

Comment: 2. Classes that have getters/setters should be DTOs. DTOs in turn should have no business logic and therefore no separate unittests.

Answer (score 6):

From Lombok 1.16.14, all generated methods will be annotated with `@lombok.Generated`.

You can exclude them from the Cobertura test report:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <instrumentation>
      <ignoreMethodAnnotation>lombok.Generated</ignoreMethodAnnotation>
    </instrumentation>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

NB. At this time, Lombok 1.16.14 has not been released. You can download the [edge release](https://projectlombok.org/download-edge.html) that contains this fix though.

Answer (score 4):

Since Cobertura 2.0, If it's only about getters and setters, you could set the ignoreTrival switch:

> Cobertura Changelog - New --ignoreTrivial switch that tells Cobertura
>   to ignore the following in the coverage report: Getter methods that
>   simply read a class field; Setter methods that set a class field;
>   Constructors that only set class fields and call a super class
>   constructor

If you wish to ignore methods more specifically, you could also use the ignoreMethodAnnotation switch:

> Cobertura Changelog - New --ignoreMethodAnnotation switch used to
>   specify an annotation that, when present on a method, will cause
>   Cobertura to ignore the method in the coverage report

Or, from maven plugin:

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> 
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>2.6</version> 
    <configuration> 
        <formats> 
            <format>xml</format> 
            <format>html</format> 
        </formats> 
        <instrumentation> 
            <ignoreTrivial>true</ignoreTrivial> 
            <excludes> 
                <exclude>**/some/trivial/classes/**</exclude> 
            </excludes> 
        </instrumentation> 
    </configuration> 
    <executions> 
        <execution> 
            <goals> 
                <goal>clean</goal> 
                <goal>check</goal> 
            </goals> 
        </execution> 
    </executions> 
</plugin>
```